# Webview don't display image in react-native

Tags: react-native

This is my code and it can't display image.

```
<WebView
   source={{html: `<img src='//i.pinimg.com/564x/41/76/2e/41762e489565279690334d5d38815b0f.jpg'>` }}
   style={{flex: 1}}
   javaScriptEnabled={true}
>
</WebView>
```

But I change src='https://i.pinimg.com/564x/41/76/2e/41762e489565279690334d5d38815b0f.jpg' and it work.
Why? Please help me

Comment: Shouldn't you close the image tag?

Comment: I have closed tag image, but It don't work.
I think issue when the src don't have "https://..."

Comment: You can reference images over `http`, with a little native configuration. Leaving off `https` will work on the web, but not within your native application. Leaving it off defaults to the current protocol your app is using, which I don't think is http/https.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because you are trying to load a non https url by using // in your WebView, which is not allowed by default.
If you open it as https the code you provide will work.

If you want to load a non https url in your webview, you should first allow the domain in your info.plist in xcode (more details here: [non-https sites in webview in RN](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/07/27/open-non-https-sites-in-webview-in-react-native.html))

Also, I would like to point that you can use `<Image>` component instead of `<WebView>` if you just want to render an image.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. Prolly i'll be using regex to replace all http with https